# non-numeric argument to binary operator in R studio

Tags: r

```
likedf <- vedio5 %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
 summarise(likes=sum(likes))
likedf

dikedf <- vedio5 %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  summarise(dislikes=sum(dislikes))
dikedf

ratiodf<-vedio5 %>% 
 round(likedf/dikedf)
```

The last two lines of this code do not work and I get the following message:
Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
Knowing that I tried to use the function: as.numric()
And it didn't work either

note : vedio5 is data frame
likes and category are columns

I want to calculate ratios of likes to dislikes

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to say without a reproducible example, but I think this is just a misunderstanding about how the pipeline works.  In your code above, here's what's happening:

First, you're making a new dataset which will have columns `category` and `likes` which will contain a single value for each category.

```
likedf <- vedio5 %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
 summarise(likes=sum(likes))
```

Next, you do the same for `dislikes`, so `dikedf` will have also two columns: `category` and `dislikes`

```
dikedf <- vedio5 %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  summarise(dislikes=sum(dislikes))
```

Now, `dikedf` and `likedf` are both themselves data frames that are independent from `vedio5`.  So, you don't need to pipe the data into the round function because both `likedf` and `dikedf` are both data frames already.  Further, even if you just did `round(likedf/dikedf)` that would still fail because you would be trying to do a mathematical operation (division) on the variables `category` in both data frames.

```
ratiodf<-vedio5 %>% 
  round(likedf/dikedf)
```

Instead, why not do everything in a single pipeline:

```
vedio5 %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  summarise(likes=sum(likes),
           dislikes = sum(dislikes)) %>% 
  mutate(ratio = likes/dislikes)
```